# iOS zeromq sometimes cannot receive message at start in pub/sub

Tags: ios, zeromq

I am using ZMQ Stable Release 3.2.4 and compile it into iOS
and also use IOS ZMQ Api.
It works perfectly most of the time. However, sometimes when start the app, the first message is missing and the receiver becomes idle all the time. After restart the app, it works well again.

Is it something I need to set in subSocket in order to make it more stable?

Here is my code:

```
IP_ADDRESS = @"127.0.0.1";

NSString *kEndPoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tcp://%@:%d", IP_ADDRESS, PUB_PORT];
self.pubSocket = [ctx socketWithType:ZMQ_PUB];
[self.pubSocket connectToEndpoint:kEndPoint];

NSString *rEndPoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tcp://%@:%d", IP_ADDRESS, SUB_PORT];
self.subSocket = [ctx socketWithType:ZMQ_SUB];
[self.subSocket connectToEndpoint:rEndPoint];

sleep(1.5); // add sleep to make sure the socket is ready

[self registerListener:self forTopic:TOPIC_topic_resolution];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    pollitems[0].socket = [subSocket socket] ;
    pollitems[0].events = ZMQ_POLLIN;

    NSData * data = [subSocket receiveDataWithFlags:ZMQ_DONTWAIT];

    // receive data and do logic here
});
```

Comment: How did make Zeromq work in iOS? Can you share your compiled Zmq lib with me? I need Zmq in my ios app but it seems Zeromq doesn't work in iOS 8.1 xCode 6

Comment: There are unofficial releases available [here](https://github.com/drewcrawford/libzmq-ios/releases). I am using that library in my app. I need some documentation/samples which can help me in implementing this stuff. Can anyone provide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our iOS apps that use zmq (libzmq) I usually set a timeout to avoid the dreaded hang forever waiting for receive... try something like this for your setsockopt:

```
    int timeout = 6000;
zmq_setsockopt(self->zmqSend, ZMQ_SNDTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(int));
zmq_setsockopt(self->zmqSend, ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(int));
```

hope that helps!

JB